# Storing Custom Fields for User on Azure AD

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to store some custom fields on a user object on Azure AD accessible through the Graph API.

I have looked at data extensions [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/opentypeextension), but it seems these can only be used for messages or events.

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add them with the Azure AD Graph API - the precursor to the Microsoft Graph API.

The schema description is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#extensionproperty-entity).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions describes the operations possible:

- Register an extension
- View registered extensions
- Write an extension value
- Remove an extension value
- Read an extension value
- Filter an extension value
- Unregister an extension

Its important to note that the extensions are registered for an application, so the application needs to be registered in the AAD instance before you can add the extensions.

Update, 2017-03-09: New announcement [you can now add custom app data using the Microsoft Graph API to user and group resources.](https://dev.office.com/blogs/adding-customer-data-to-resources-in-Microsoft-Graph-preview)